# Selective strip tags in TextMate

Tags: html, css, editor, tags, textmate

Is there a way to strip HTML tags selectively in **TextMate** - you can easily do this in **Dreamweaver**.
TextMate allows you to strip all HTML tags but I would like to get rid of only, let's say all the `<span>`'s and `<font>`'s.

On a similar topic, is there a way to get rid of all the inline css styles?

Comment: I have nothing else to add here other than to say that I love the Space Moose icon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use replace with regular expressions? E.g. to get rid of all inline css styles you would just replace

```
 style=".*"
```

with nothing (empty string). Note the leading space.

Comment: Quantors are greedy by default.

Comment: Here at work I'm on Windows. I just tested on Notepad++. If TextMate does greedy matching by default, just use the non-greedy version: style=".*?"

Comment: Notepad++ has a very limited regular expression support. http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/regExpList.php

Comment: In contrast to that: TextMate’s regular expression support http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, but there's always the option of doing a Find/Replace for `<span>` (and `</span>`, obviously) and leaving the "Replace" field empty. Of course, this becomes a little more problematic if you've got spans with varying class/id attributes or what-have-you, then you're getting into RegExp territory.

That should at least give you a start, though. I'd be interested to hear what anyone else has to offer, though. Textmate is so customizable that I'm sure there's a better solution than what I've offered!